# Collision detection for UI elements with transparency

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, collision-detection

I have a UI framework rendered with OpenGL/OpenGL ES. Some UI elements have transparent areas. Now I use bounding rectangle for collision, but in some particular cases where transparent parts from one element overlaps other element it fails to detect correct element.

I don't want to retain a duplicate of the used texture(as a last solution I may retain only the alpha channel).

How do you think I should approach the collision detection in this case? The solution should be fast and memory friendly.

Is OpenGL/OpenGL ES texture memory reading fast enough to use it(rarely, only on events) for getting alpha value for one pixel? Does this reading break OpenGL/OpenGL ES pipeline?

EDIT:

To make it more clear, I only need Object-Point collision - it is a UI library, but some buttons for example might not have rectangle forms and their bounding boxes might overlap. I need to detect correctly the pressed button in this case.

Comment: @genpfault Why did you remove my opengl tag? Some users might think I use this only with OpenGL ES and this is not true.

Comment: I generally try to keep the `opengl` and `opengl-es` tags separate since on most counts they're pretty different.  Must have been re-tagging on autopilot yesterday, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the UI element doesn't change you could declare a CGPathRef for each button and then use CGPathContainsPoint to detect which one is pressed. You may have to loop through every button but the check done by core graphics is fast enough not to slow down the app.

Note that this is pixel perfect detection. You can't get faster or more precise without using physics engine.

EDIT :

Using [PIP](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) algorithm for this case will work...and as you noticed ..it has a hole in it. You can use the same idea for multiple holes also.

[image]

Comment: CGPathRef and CGPathContainsPoint are Apple specific, I can't use this on PC. Also the path approach fails when you have a "hole" in the object.

Comment: then what you're looking for is [point-in-polygon problem](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) . Also you didn't specify the platform you're using

Comment: Thank you for help, but I think it is very hard to describe the object when it contains "holes" with a polygon.

Comment: My problem is not the algorithm for detecting if the point is in polygon, but the algorithm to describe my shape as a polygon. It can be any shape, with many "holes" in it of any kind. If I use few points, the collision will be imprecise. If I use many points the algorithm will take quite very much to check, and eventually will consume more memory than a bitmap.